# Using Alphabetical Characters as Actions. Mac OSX NSEvent? SKAction?

Tags: macos, swift

I'm creating a 2d game based on a tile map, its my first program that I'm doing myself so think of that when you kindly take the time to answer me :)

I've built the UI and a small map, and I finally got my character to move with the arrow keys. But I can't find anything on how to set up button input.

Example:

Press <kbd>Q</kbd> - (function)

Press <kbd>W</kbd> - (function)

If <kbd>Q</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> are pressed within 1.5 seconds - function

Here is my current code, do I add these events to this bit of code? or do I write a new override function? I've tried and failed multiple times doing both.

```
override func keyDown(event: NSEvent) {
    if event.modifierFlags & .NumericPadKeyMask == .NumericPadKeyMask { 
        for keyChar in event.charactersIgnoringModifiers!.unicodeScalars {
            switch UInt32(keyChar) {
                case 0xF700: //up key
                    DidMoveUp()
                case 0xF701: //down key
                    DidMoveDown()
                case 0xF702: //left key
                    DidMoveLeft()
                case 0xF703: //right key
                    DidMoveRight()
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You said you figured out how to register the arrow key events in Swift. Could you please provide that? I have been having a hard time figuring it out. Thanks! Note: Every time I press a key after implementing the code in your answer, I get the OS X reject noise.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the solution! 
Credit to User: Gilian Joosen

```
func returnChar(theEvent: NSEvent!) -> Character?{
    let s: String = theEvent.characters!
    for char in s {
        return char}
    return nil
}

override func keyUp(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let s: String = String(self.returnChar(theEvent)!)
    switch(s){
    case "w":
        explosion()
        break
    case "s":
        DidMoveDown()
        break
    case "d":
        DidMoveUp()
        break
    case "a":
        DidMoveRight()
        break


    default:
        println("default")
    }
}
```